# What's wrong with this javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm using javascript to switch out tables based on the time. But i'm getting an error in DW.

```
       <script type="text/JavaScript">
<!--
function changeWebsite() {
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();    

 if (7 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 18) {
       document.write('  <table id="Table_01" width="200" height="400" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/websitelist_tumblr_VC01.png" width="200" height="45" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://www.itsnotch.com"
                onmouseover="window.status='Visit My Biography Website';  return true;"
                onmouseout="window.status='';  return true;">
                <img src="http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/websitelist_tumblr_VC02.png" width="200" height="75" border="0" alt="ItsNotch.com"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://www.notchtheguru.com"
                onmouseover="window.status='My Tumblr';  return true;"
                onmouseout="window.status='';  return true;">
                <img src="http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/NotchTheGuru.comVC.png" width="200" height="119" border="0" alt="Tumblr"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://www.bignotch.com"
                onmouseover="window.status='Welcome to My Music Website';  return true;"
                onmouseout="window.status='';  return true;">
                <img src="http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/websitelist_tumblr_VC04.png" width="200" height="161" border="0" alt="NotchTheGuru.com"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
 ');
      }

       else {
       document.write(' <table id="Table_01" width="200" height="400" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/websitelist_tumblr_01.png" width="200" height="45" alt=""></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://www.itsnotch.com"
                onmouseover="window.status='Visit My Biography Website';  return true;"
                onmouseout="window.status='';  return true;">
                <img src="http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/websitelist_tumblr_02.png" width="200" height="75" border="0" alt="ItsNotch.com"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://www.notchtheguru.com"
                onmouseover="window.status='My Tumblr';  return true;"
                onmouseout="window.status='';  return true;">
                <img src="http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/NotchTheGuru.com.png" width="200" height="119" border="0" alt="Tumblr"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://www.bignotch.com"
                onmouseover="window.status='Welcome to My Music Website';  return true;"
                onmouseout="window.status='';  return true;">
                <img src="http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/websitelist_tumblr_04.png" width="200" height="161" border="0" alt="NotchTheGuru.com"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
 ');
      }

}

changeWebsite();
-->
```

the error is on line 7  'document.write('

Comment: The error is the commented lines. =-P

Comment: You cannot break lines in JavaScript strings just by pressing ENTER.

Answer (score 3):

1. JavaScript does not support multiline strings.
2. You have unescaped single quotes inside of the string (which is delimited with single quotes).
   For example, you **must** change:

   ```
   onmouseover="window.status='Visit My Biography Website';
   ```

   to:

   ```
   onmouseover="window.status=\'Visit My Biography Website\';
   ```

---

For detailed information, run your code through [JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/).

> WARNING: JSLint will hurt your feelings.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't write this much HTML code from your javascript. If you do this often, your code will quickly become unreadable and it's also a nightmare performance wise.

Nearly all the HTML code you're writing is the same, you better do something like this :

HTML Code :

```
<table id="Table_01" width="200" height="400" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/websitelist_tumblr_01.png" width="200" height="45" alt="" id="image1"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://www.itsnotch.com"
                onmouseover="window.status='Visit My Biography Website';  return true;"
                onmouseout="window.status='';  return true;">
                <img src="http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/websitelist_tumblr_02.png" width="200" height="75" border="0" alt="ItsNotch.com" id="image2"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://www.notchtheguru.com"
                onmouseover="window.status='My Tumblr';  return true;"
                onmouseout="window.status='';  return true;">
                <img src="http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/NotchTheGuru.com.png" width="200" height="119" border="0" alt="Tumblr" id="image3"></a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="http://www.bignotch.com"
                onmouseover="window.status='Welcome to My Music Website';  return true;"
                onmouseout="window.status='';  return true;">
                <img src="http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/websitelist_tumblr_04.png" width="200" height="161" border="0" alt="NotchTheGuru.com" id="image4"></a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
```

Javascript code :

```
<script type="text/JavaScript">
function changeWebsite() {
var currentTime = new Date().getHours();    

if (7 <= currentTime&&currentTime < 18) {
    var baseURL = "http://itsnotch.com/tumblr/images/";
    document.getElementById("image1").src = baseURL + "websitelist_tumblr_VC01.png";
    document.getElementById("image2").src = baseURL + "websitelist_tumblr_VC02.png";
    document.getElementById("image3").src = baseURL + "NotchTheGuru.comVC.png";
    document.getElementById("image4").src = baseURL + "websitelist_tumblr_VC04.png";
}
changeWebsite()
</script>
```

As a little piece of advise, you shouldn't change the status bar yourself when someone `mouseover` your link, this really piss some people off, me for example.

Comment: +1 for pointing out how not DRY the code is. I didn't realize it was a big/copy paste job.

Answer (score 0):

you're mixing single quotes and double quotes, there's the error, you need to escape them.